# Installing Informix CSDK in an Ubuntu Docker container

Tags: docker, informix

I'm trying to install `ibm.csdk.4.50.FC3.LNX` in a Docker container based on Ubuntu 18.

I run in the container the installation file as follows:

```
root@mycontainer:/usr/src/ibm.csdk.4.50.FC3.LNX# ./installclientsdk -i console
```

But I get this error:

> One or more prerequisite system libraries are not installed on your
>   computer. Install libdl.so.2, libcrypt.so.1, libpam.so.0,
>   libstdc++.so.6, libm.so.6, libgcc_s.so.1, libc.so.6, libncurses.so.5
>   and then restart the IBM Informix installation program.
>
> The installation cannot succeed until the minimum requirements are
>   met. For more information about the prerequisites, see your
>   Installation Guide or check with your System Administrator.

However those files are already in the container in the following paths:

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpam.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5
```

How can I install it?

Comment: That message is a little generic so maybe there is something else missing. Try adding what is mentioned in lines 10 and 11 from the docker developer-sandbox image script: 
`https://hub.docker.com/layers/ibmcom/informix-developer-sandbox/latest/images/sha256-678250715879a7cbdd2ea658ff7ecd7087dcaf0b8e39d47c936916edff62c5ec?context=explore`

Comment: Ok just tried, but the error persists.

Comment: running `apt install unixodbc-dev` seems solving

Comment: Can you share your dockerfile? I am also stuck similar problem.. @floatingpurr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `apt install unixodbc-dev` seems fixing.

You might want to install also `unixodbc`

Answer (score 0):

We have similar issue where we are running shell script which runs dbaccess inside the docker container. but as we run the docker as root user it is trying to use root user to connect to the informix db server. is there a way we can configure user name and password for dbaccess to use the configured userId instead of root.

Comment: You can try to go over some of the pointers in this thread: https://community.cisco.com/t5/contact-center/connection-to-ccx-database-via-python/td-p/4028370

PS: maybe I'd be better opening a new question about it here in SO.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).